# Flutter doctor --> Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)

Tags: android, flutter, toolchain

I have a question so I think I dowlnloaded everything correctly but I still get this massage when I type in "flutter dictir" in cmd.
When I run "path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest" as recommended nothing happens.
So could you help me to download it anyways?

[thecode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jxaqe.png)

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
X cmdline-tools component is missing
Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
X Android license status unknown.
Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Answer (score 12):

Open android studio then go to settings then SDK manager. Check the command line tools if it's not checked (most times it's not), then finish and let it download that plugin. Once you've installed the cmd tools, run flutter doctor and accept the licenses when prompted

Comment: Thank yot for you tip but it doesn't help.

Comment: If you've installed the cmd tools then run flutter doctor and accept the licenses when prompted

Comment: Yes, thank you I could solve it :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Android SDK path.

Go to where flutter is installed **flutter config --android-sdk android_sdk_path**
execute the command.

ex) **flutter config --android-sdk C:\tools\AndroidSDK**

Answer (score 0):

1. Run this `flutter config --android-sdk <path where you saved Android studio SDK>` for e.g. in my case it was `flutter config --android-sdk D:\AS_SDK` (basically navigate SDK to the custom location).
2. Go to Android Studio, on the first page where you start a project, find the option to look for more settings, there you go to SDK manager and then select and install "Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)" (size at the time of writing this is 108.9mb).
3. Now that you have the Android SDK navigated to the correct location and the latest command-line tools installed, run this `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and for every question it asks while confirming the licenses say "**y**".

Answer (score 0):

1- Download platform-tools from SDK platform tools :

- https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools
- go to `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` and replace the platform-tools folder with the new one.

2- if build-tools (version number) exception appears,

- go and download that build-tools with that version number from:
  https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/build-tools
- go to `C:\Users\<UserName>\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools` and replace the folder with that version number  with the new one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an illustration how to do it [Screenshot for Android-tootl-chain download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX8m0.jpg)

Comment: please add some more information. A textual answer with breadcrumbs is easier than a image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).